# Redis Resque Not Posting Fast Enough

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque

I have a Ruby on Rails app.

App and Database hosted on one server 
redis server hosted on another

Everything seems to work fine. But i just found out how to check my Queues.

And as you can see in my information below. It has added 14k pending in the time it took to process only 450

```
1.9.1 :038 > Resque.info
 => {:pending=>616025, :processed=>186533, :queues=>4, :workers=>8, :working=>8, :failed=>24557, :servers=>["redis://ipaddress:6379/0"], :environment=>"production"}

1.9.1 :040 > Resque.info
 => {:pending=>630945, :processed=>186989, :queues=>4, :workers=>8, :working=>8, :failed=>24560, :servers=>["redis://ipaddress:6379/0"], :environment=>"production"}
1.9.1 :041 >
```

How can i increase efficiency and get the records posted faster

Comment: It is very hard to tell, as we don't know what your workers are doing. The problem is not posting to the queue, it is _processing_ the queue - events are building up faster than they are processed.

Comment: is there a way to clear the Queues so i can see how it is working with a clean que

Comment: https://gist.github.com/denmarkin/1228863